# require_once doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php

If I try to open this simple file in my Browser:

```
<?php

require_once 'classes/settings.php';

class Mysql {
    
    private $conn;
    
    function __construct() {
        
        $this->conn = new mysqli (DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_MEMBER) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
        if ($this->conn->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->conn->connect_errno . ") " . $this->conn->connect_error;
}
 //echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
    }
    
    function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {
        
        $query = "SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
        LIMIT 1";
        
        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
            
            $stmt->bind_param('ss',$un,$pwd);
            $stmt->execute();
            
            if($stmt->fetch()) {    
                $stmt->close();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
 ?>
```

I receive this warning error:

```
Warning: require_once(classes/settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or 
directory in /var/www/classes/Mysql.php on line 3 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed 
opening required 'classes/settings.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') 
in /var/www/classes/Mysql.php on line 3
```

I can't understand why, the file `setting.php` is in that folder, so what is the problem?

---

**EDIT**:

if I do the same this with another file for example this:

```
<?php 
require_once 'classes/settings.php';


 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $pass = "pass";

 $databaseName = "membership";
 $tableName = "users";

 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // 1) Connect to mysql database
 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

 $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
 $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // 2) Query database for data
 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");            //query
 $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    

 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // 3) echo result as json 
 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

In this way, it works without problem, I can't understand why the file and the path is right because in this second piece code all work.

Comment: Shouldn't you `require_once` just 'settings.php' here? Or '../classes/settings.php', if you're more, well, industrious. )

Comment: is the filename settings.php or setting.php?  May be the issue

Comment: also try the absolute path and see what happens  /var/www/classes/settings.php

Comment: What does `echo 'File: ', __FILE__, "<br />\n"; echo 'cwd: ', getcwd(),  "<br />\n";` before the require_once print? Keep in mind that a relative path is relative to the current working directory (cwd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are with in the classes folder already you have two options

First option is to use a relative path

`require_once 'settings.php';`

Second option is to use an absolute path

`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/settings.php'`

Answer (score 5):

Your script, `var/www/classes/Mysql.php`, is already *in* the classes directory. The file you're including is in the same directory. Remove the `classes/` and use:

```
require_once 'settings.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/settings.php');
```